# Access view model in controller after being edited in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making an app that has a shopping cart like feature in it. I want to allow users to view items, and then add them to a cart.

The basic workflow I want to follow is something like:

1. User views possible items.
2. User selects an item, and the detail view pops up.
3. User selects options they want (size/colour/quantity/etc).
4. User clicks on "Add to cart".
5. Item/options are added to their shopping cart.

I think I have it worked out, right up to step 5. This I cant get working.

To display the item/options, I'm using a view model. This contains the details of the item, a list of possible sizes/colours, and a field for the selected size and colour.

In the view I have a button "Add to Cart", which calls a method in the same controller that generated the item view model.

Now I need to get my hands on the item view model, as the user edited, so I know what size/colour/quantity they want. But I cant seem to get access to it.

I'm loosely basing this workflow from the Contoso University example, where they use "TryUpdateModelAsync" to update records when edited (NOTE: NOT MY CODE):

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var studentToUpdate = await _context.Students.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
            studentToUpdate,
            "",
            s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                                             "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                                             "see your system administrator.");
            }
        }
        return View(studentToUpdate);
    }
```

But his does not work with a view model (or so I cant get it working).

So, my question is this: After a controller passes a viewmodel to a view, and the view calls a method on the same controller, how do I get the viewmodel as it was edited in the view?

Sorry if this is a bit of a confused question - I've been working on this for a while without making any progress.

--- EDIT ---
Editing this to include some of my code. Firstly, I have the view model (ItemDetailViewModel):

```
    public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
    public ItemDetailViewModel()
    {

    }

    public ItemDetailViewModel(Item item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public List<ItemSize> Sizes { get; set; }
    public List<ItemColour> Colours { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedSizeId { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedColourId { get; set; }
    public SelectList SizesSelectList { get; set; }
    public SelectList ColoursSelectList { get; set; }

    public bool HasSizes
    {
        get
        {
            if (Sizes == null)
                return false;
            return Sizes.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    public bool HasColours
    {
        get
        {
            if (Colours == null)
                return false;
            return Colours.Count > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have in the ItemDetailkController this class for generating the detail:

```
        [Authorize]
    public async Task< IActionResult> Detail(string storeType,int menuid, int id)
    {
        ApplicationUser appUser = ConstantData.GetApplicationUser(_context, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
        if (appUser == null)
            return null;
        //Item item = await _context.Item.FindAsync(id);
        Item item = await _context.Item
            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
            .Include(i => i.ItemPriceBreaks)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        if (item.CustomerID.HasValue && item.CustomerID != appUser.CustomerID)
            return null;
        ItemDetailViewModel itemDetailModel = new ItemDetailViewModel(item);
        itemDetailModel.Sizes = await _context.ItemSize
            .Where(s => s.ItemID == id)
            .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
            .ToListAsync();
        if (item.Type != ItemTypeEnum.StandardItem)
        itemDetailModel.Colours = await _context.ItemColour
                .Where(c => c.ItemID == id)
                .ToListAsync();
        if (itemDetailModel.HasSizes)
            itemDetailModel.SizesSelectList = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList(itemDetailModel.Sizes, "ID", "Name");
        if (itemDetailModel.HasColours)
            itemDetailModel.ColoursSelectList = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList(itemDetailModel.Colours, "ID", "Name");
        return View(itemDetailModel);
    }
```

This is the view (Detail.cshtml) which displays the view model:

```
 <h2>Item Detail</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Details for this item</h4>
    <hr />
    <form asp-action="AddToCart">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item.Description)</dd>
            <dt>Short Description</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item.ShortDescription)</dd>
            <dt>Features</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item.Features)</dd>
            @if (Model.HasSizes)
            {
                <dt>Size</dt>
                <dd>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSizeId, Model.SizesSelectList, "Select a size")
                </dd>
            }
            @if (Model.HasColours)
            {
                <dt>Colour</dt>
                <dd>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedColourId, Model.ColoursSelectList, "Select a colour")</dd>
            }

        </dl>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th style="text-align:right">Unit Price Ex Tax</th>
                <th style="text-align:right">Unit Price Inc Tax</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var price in Model.Item.ItemPriceBreaks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => price.Quantity)</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => price.UnitPriceExTax)</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => price.UnitPriceIncTax)</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

And then finally, in the same controller as before, I have this method:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("AddToCart")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(int id)
    {
        // How do I get ItemDetailViewModel from here?
        return null;
    }
```

So - what do I need to put in "AddToCart" to get the modified ItemDetailViewModel?

Comment: It works like this: browser requests page => controller action is hit => controller creates vm and sends it to the view then it sends the view to the browser. The view also has the controller and action of where it will be posted afterwards. When the user edits the item in the view, the user posts it (using the browser) back to the server (controller). It uses the information in the view to post it. Your controller needs an action to accept the post. Here you will get the viewmodel posted back to you.

Comment: I have an action in the controller that accepts this post (the debugger catches it), but I'm not sure how to get the view model from within there.

Comment: I do not see your controller's action that accepts the view model. Did you forget to add it to  your question?

Comment: I didnt include my code. The bit above is a sample. I'll edit it to include snippets of my code.

Comment: Your form is generating inputs based on `ItemDetailViewModel`, therefore you POST method needs to be `public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(ItemDetailViewModel model)` and the parameter will be bound with selected values for `SelectedSizeId` and `SelectedColourId` (all the other properties will be there default values, so you should at least have an input to identify the ID of the item, and you should also be including validation to ensure options for Size and Colour are selected if they are displayed.

Comment: You also noted _selects quantity_ but neither your view model or view seems to contain anything related to that.

Comment: Thanks. That was it! I had tried that before, but so many values in the view model were null, I assumed it wasnt working. Now I understand it a bit more.

Comment: And yes, the quantity bit will come later. I just wanted to get the basic functionality working before I started adding quantities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160836/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-shaggs).